# NPM Bamboo task can't find package.json because of wrong dir

Tags: bamboo, npm-install

My **npm** task yields the following thing in the logs:

```
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/{name of project-plan-job}/package.json'
```

Therefore Sails.js doesn't get installed and the **Node.js** task tells me that I can't run the Node app.

Now, I guess this happens because of the directory hierarchy. The repository is structures as follows: **repo-root/app/package.json**, whereas usually the `.json` file is directly under the repo root dir.
Do I have to configure the `Source Code Checkout` task in some specific way?

Comment: Setting the working subdirectory in your Bamboo task accordingly should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set sub-directory as /home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/{name of project-plan-job}/ in the Bamboo stage.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced options -> Working subdirectory -> \FolderName
[image]